# Issue while installing hadoop-2.2.0 in linux 64 bit machine

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2, hadoop-plugins, hadoop-partitioning

Using this link ,tried installing Hadoop version - 2.2.0(single node cluster)in ubuntu 12.04(64 bit machine)

http://bigdatahandler.com/hadoop-hdfs/installing-single-node-hadoop-2-2-0-on-ubuntu/

while formatting the hdfs file system via namenode using the following command

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

when i'm doing that ,getting the following issue,

14/08/07 10:38:39 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in trailing section.

What shall i need to do inorder to solve the following issue?

Mapred-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there anything more in the mapred-site.xml? I cant see any line number 27.

Comment: now copied the whole thing check it out

Comment: Still cannot see line 27. If You left an [enter] press after last line,maybe its causing issue.

Comment: Try implementing from [this](http://raseshmori.wordpress.com/2012/09/23/install-hadoop-2-0-1-yarn-nextgen/)

Comment: Like @Abhishek said, everything so far hints at a problem on line 27 of the XML, but unfortunately we're not seeing a line 27 come through in your post.  You might try looking at a hex representation of the file (run something like `hexdump` or `xxd` on the file).  That could tell you if there is something odd at the end of the XML, like a control character.

Comment: ya that was an issue....Fixed it .........Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

14/08/07 10:38:39 FATAL namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml; **lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 1;** Content is not allowed in trailing section

Probably some caracter in your XML that you forget to erase. Please post your full XML. Like @Abhishek said!

Comment: ya that was an issue...Fixed it ...Thanks for ur help